# Adding tables to dashboard pages programmatically?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, filters, actions, pluggable

I think that is not possible with some actions or filters, I know that I can do it just with html and using right css styles, and of course php to achieve what I need, or to write some minde actions. Is there already some predefined functions for this or not? 
Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? your question currently makes no sense, add some info

Comment: @Bainternet ,thn for response, for example I want to add table that will have before it's content with fields and pagination for posts, or users, or custom post type, or images,...

Comment: @user1147 I'm still not sure what your question is.  WordPress gives you a way to modify posts, users and custom post types in the dashboard.  You don't have to create them programmatically - WordPress does is for you.

Comment: @Bainternet Sorry,maybe if I say this way : if I add custom option page under settings tab, and I want to display users in table with pagination, search option, so is there a way to build these table programmatically, or only way is to create table, apply wp styles,...

Comment: Are you talking about something like this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table

Comment: @Bainternet Hey, yes, I really didn't know about that.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in that case take a look at [this tutorial](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/03/native-admin-tables-wordpress/) on how to use the native WP_List_Table

Comment: @Bainernet Hi, thank you, I have already found that post.Thank you for the help.